# Android - enterAlways not working, Toolbar doesn't scroll with the rest of the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-scrollview, android-appbarlayout

I am following this guide [CodePath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#responding-to-scroll-events) trying to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LWAD.gif). I don't want a Expandable and Collapsible Toolbar. I just want a simple `Toolbar` that scrolls up with the Layout and then shows up as soon as one starts going up (not when it reaches all the way to the top).
I followed the Codepath guide and created this [Layout](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/589cc719416cdd39c2188da98b6c474e). But the scrolling of the NestedScrollView doesn't work here.
So I found an answer on StackOverflow that suggested enclosing the contents of the `CoordinatorLayout` in a `LinearLayout` and the scrolling worked ([NewLayout](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/2c496400be7f722edd74ea9f994ce96d)). But the `Toolbar` doesn't scroll with the rest of the Layout and stays fixed at the top and I was hoping like something that was mentioned on the Codepath guide,like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LWAD.gif).

What am I doing wrong here ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

NestedScrollView should be outside appbarlayout, see the example code below :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     <!-- Your scrolling content -->

 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             ...
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
             ...
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Reference : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Hope it works !

Comment: Thanks for the answer Abhinav, but it doesn't work as I thought it would. Now what I get is a Toolbar on top, followed by completely blank area but when I scroll, I see my main Layout-content which is scrollable in the size of a Toolbar, so the content is scrollable _inside_ a bottom Toolbar. [This](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/151c06bad35aadd2c86f4fd6061220cf) is what I did.

Comment: Do I need to use a `TabLayout` ? Because my layout doesn't require any.